# ActiveWorkbook.Close 1004 runtime error, missing folder path

Tags: excel, vba

```vb
Sub LoopThroughFolder()

Dim table As Range
Dim FSO
Dim month As String
Dim year As String
Dim FileName As String
Dim OldFileName As String
Dim MainPath As String
Dim ClientPath As String
Dim FullPath As String
Dim FileToOpen As Workbook
Dim Text As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("FileName")

month = ws.Range("E8")
year = ws.Range("F8")
OldFileName = ws.Range("R5")

MainPath = "C:\Document\documents\CPREIF_daily_test\"

ClientPath = MainPath & year & "\" & month & " - " & year & "\"

Set table = Range("B8", Range("B8").End(xlToRight).End(xlDown))

For Each Row In table.Rows
    
    Text = Row.Cells(1, 1)
    FileName = Row.Cells(1, 7)
    
    Set FileToOpen = Workbooks.Open(ClientPath & OldFileName, UpdateLinks:=0)
    
    Range("B4").ClearContents
    Range("B4") = Text
    Range("B4").NumberFormat = "dddd mmmm d" & ", " & "yyyy"
    ActiveWorkbook.Close True, ClientPath & FileName

Next Row

MsgBox "Client Files Turned"

End Sub
```

I loop through each row of a table, renaming the workbook and changing the date within a cell, based off each row in a table.

When I run the code within the VBA editor, the code works.
When I run the macro from a button, I receive a runtime error.

> 1004 runtime error, missing folder path

The line that breaks:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Close True, ClientPath & FileName
```

Comment: `Set table = Range("B8", Range("B8").End(xlToRight).End(xlDown))` works off the `ActiveSheet`, which may or may not be the one you want.

Comment: Also, why are you using `ActiveWorkbook.Close` instead of `FileToOpen.Close`?

Comment: `Set table = ws.Range("B8", ws.Range("B8").End(xlToRight).End(xlDown))`

Comment: Lol. This is my first Vba project. Your first solution worked. Thank you! I will implement FileToOpen.Close. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Now I am getting Application defined or object defined error

Comment: If you're getting an error there's not much we can do without your current code and the exact line where the error occurs.